# Memcached get may return "not found" even though the key is set

Tags: php, memcached

I'm using the Memcached extension in PHP, and I observe a strange behavior.

Sometimes, `Memcached::get` returns `false` with a result of `RES_NOTFOUND`, even though the key has been set with `Memcached::set`. This happens a few times an hour on a server with about 300 Memcached requests per second.

First I thought, somehow the set requests may fail and delete the key instead of updating it. Now I made a statistic about the different results, and I only receive RES_SUCCESS or RES_NOTFOUND. This makes me think that any error that happens while getting a key reports as not found, even though there are many result codes documented.

Is there a way to get more precise result codes? Or is it just impossible to rely on finding an existing key?

By the way, we are using PHP 7.2.

Comment: Do you check return results from calling memcache' ::set function?

Comment: @Daniel Yes they were all RES_SUCCESS.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get more precise code error or description, but you can try to nail it down to a particular key and try to find a pattern by logging the occurrences of RES_NOTFOUND, or checking the [log file](https://serverfault.com/questions/422350/memcached-debuging-server-logs-monitor-the-memcached-servers) for memcache.